# Making a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So i'm fairly new to Android dev and I wanted to make the follow code run on a separate thread,

```
public void game (final Button[] temp) {
            if (temp[0].getBackground().equals(temp[1].getBackground()) )
            {
                temp[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                temp[1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                finishedGame++;
            } else

            {
                temp[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                temp[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
            }
}
```

so I changed the code to the following:

```
public void game (final Button[] temp) {
    class startGame implements Runnable {
        startGame() {}
        public synchronized void run() {
            if (temp[0].getBackground().equals(temp[1].getBackground()) )
            {
                temp[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                temp[1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                finishedGame++;
            } else

            {
                temp[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                temp[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just wanted to know if I did this right and where exactly do I put the code to call this method, before I had it in the onClick in an OnClickListener

```
View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            button[0].setBackground(image[0]);
            if (state == 1) {
                temp[1] = button[0];
                game(temp);
            }
        }
    };
```

game(temp) would be what I used to call the method before. 
I think the code I need to call the thread is

```
Thread xxx = new Thread(startGame);
xxx.start();
```

but I'm not sure and not sure where to put it.

Comment: The code you need to start a thread is `Thread xxx = new Thread(new startGame()); xxx.start();` and you put it wherever you want to start the thread.

Comment: So the same place I have game(temp)? And do I need both lines in the Onclicklistener or can I have the first line outside the listener?

Comment: Well, I thought you wanted the `game` method to start a new thread, so put it in the `game` method. And move the class `startGame` outside `game` if it's confusing you - a class declaration won't do anything by itself.

Comment: Alright so I have 
"Thread check = new Thread(new startGame());
        check.start();"
inside game and the startGame outside game but when I run the app when it finishes the if statement inside startGame it causes my app to stop, do you know what may of caused this?

Comment: Is it because I didn't send the Button array temp into the new thread? 



public void game (final Button[] temp) {

        Thread check = new Thread(new startGame());
        check.start();
    }

Comment: You can start a thread, but you will soon discover that you must move all the UI updates back to the main (UI) thread or your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to UI elements (views) must occur on the main UI thread - so calling 
    temp[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
or
    temp[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
will fail.

In your onClick method do something like the following

```
View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        button[0].setBackground(image[0]);
        if (state == 1) {
            temp[1] = button[0];

            view.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (temp[0].getBackground().equals(temp[1].getBackground()) )
                    {
                        temp[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        temp[1].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        finishedGame++;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                         temp[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                         temp[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```